# ajax and datatable refresh button

Tags: javascript, ajax, datatable

(sorry for my english)

my problem : I have a function who send a request who draw the table with or without parameter. First on the onload of the page, and after with a search click who send a param (data actor etc).
I have two button (in each row) in the table (modify (modifier) and delete (supprimer) a row) and my BIG problem is, when I use the delete button AFTER a search click, first, the program want to delete the old line and next second the program want to delete the good line. The most strange is the modify button works perfectly.. it never deceive row...

Apparently the button will erase the line of the first table (before the search) but it does not suit all!!

```
function scanrecherche(environnementDep, statutDep){   

var table = $('#etableau').DataTable(
{                
    "ajax": 
    {            
        "url": 'url',
        "type": "GET",
        "dataSrc": '',
         data: {"actor": actor, "version": version, "environnement": environnement, "appState": appState, "appli": appli, "nbmax": nbmax}
    },
    "aaSorting": [[ 6, 'asc' ]],
    "destroy": true,
    "columns":
            [
                {"data": "actor"},
                {"data": "version"},
                {"data": "environnement"},
                {"data": "appState"},
                {"data": "appli"},
                {"data": "note"},
                {"data": "cDate"},
                {"data": "updateDate"},
                {"data": "instancid"},
                {"className": 'modifier',
                    "orderable": false,
                    "data": null,
                    "defaultContent": ''},
                {"className": 'supprimer',
                    "orderable": false,
                    "data": null,
                    "defaultContent": ''}
            ],
    language:
            {
                processing: "Traitement en cours...",
                search: "Rechercher&nbsp;:",
                lengthMenu: "Afficher _MENU_ &eacute;l&eacute;ments",
                info: "Affichage de l'&eacute;lement _START_ &agrave; _END_ sur _TOTAL_ &eacute;l&eacute;ments",
                infoEmpty: "Affichage de l'&eacute;lement 0 &agrave; 0 sur 0 &eacute;l&eacute;ments",
                infoFiltered: "(filtr&eacute; de _MAX_ &eacute;l&eacute;ments au total)",
                infoPostFix: "",
                loadingRecords: "Chargement en cours...",
                zeroRecords: "Aucun &eacute;l&eacute;ment &agrave; afficher",
                emptyTable: "Aucune donnée disponible dans le tableau",
                paginate: {previous: "Pr&eacute;c&eacute;dent",next: "Suivant"}
            },
            "columnDefs":
            [   
                {"width": "150px", "targets": 5},
                {"width": "130px", "targets": 6},
                {"width": "100px", "targets": 7}
            ],             
         "fnRowCallback": function( nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex, iDisplayIndexFull ) 
         {
                if (aData.appState === "Active")
                    nRow.className=( "Active" );
         }
}); 


$('#etableau tbody').on('click', 'td.modifier', function () 
{
    var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
    var row = table.row(tr);

    var value = row.data().cDate;
    location.href = "Modifier.html?Date="+value;
});

$('#etableau tbody').on('click', 'td.supprimer', function () 
{    
    var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
    var row = table.row(tr);

    if (row.data().appState === "Active")
    {
        alert("Attention : La suppression d'une version Active est impossible");
    }
    else
    {                    
        var r = confirm("Vous êtes sur le point de supprimer la ligne : \n\n  Version : "+row.data().version+"\n  Date : "+row.data().cDate+"\n  Environnement : "+row.data().environnement+"\n  Application : "+row.data().appli+"\n  Statut : "+row.data().appState+" \n\nEtes vous sûr?");
        if (r === true) 
        {           
            $("#MENU").hide();
            $("#MENUload").show();
            delURL(row.data().cDate, row.data().version);
        } 
    }        
});
```

}

Answer (score 0):

the joke is.. everytime I use the "search" button, it call "scanrecherche" function and recreate the 
$('#etableau tbody').on('click', 'td.modifier', function () ) and
$('#etableau tbody').on('click', 'td.supprimer', function () )....